# Overcoming limitation with polymorphic type in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a type like so,

```
data AgentSpec a = AgentSpec 
                     { agent :: a
                     , events :: [ByteString] 
                     } deriving (Show)
```

and other types like so,

```
data Java = Java
data Php = Php
```

I am trying to create a function of type,

```
allEvents :: [AgentSpec a] -> [ByteString]
allEvents aspec = concatMap events aspec
```

But I am unable to create values of type `[AgentSpec a]`

If I do,

```
allEvents [AgentSpec Java ["event1, "event2"], AgentSpec Php ["event3, "event4"]]
```

it does not typecheck and understandably so. It doesn't type check because, `AgentSpec Java` is not `AgentSpec a`

So I understand why it does not work. But I do not know how to overcome this limitation without writing a lot of duplicate code.

One alternatve is to manually construct a list of type,

```
allEvents :: [ByteString]
allEvents = ["event1", "event2", "event3", "event4"].
```

But I feel like I'm simply rewriting things I've already modelled in my types. Is there any way to make use of my existing types to get what I want? Which is just a concatenated list of bytestrings of all the AgentSpecs

Comment: Do you actually need `AgentSpec Java` and `AgentSpec Php` to be distinct types? You could just do `data Handler = Java | Php`

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'm writing it as a library. So If someone were to use my library, wouldn't it be easier for them to just create their own type instead of messing with the abstractions used in the library? Because if I do as you suggested, then they will have to modify the library by adding their custom `Handler` with `data Handler = Java | Php | Custom`

Comment: See https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type#Dynamic_dispatch_mechanism_of_OOP

Comment: On a side note I would use `data AgentSpec a = AS {events :: [ByteString]} deriving (Show)` with `a` being a phantom type so you don't have to drag the agent parameter around.

Comment: If the definition is really something like `allEvents aspec = concatMap events aspec`, then the application of every call to `events` must be independent i.e. do not rely on any additional information but a single `AgentSpec`, so why you need such a function in your library at first place?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
allEvents [AgentSpec Java ["event1, "event2"], AgentSpec Php ["event3, "event4"]]
```

doesn't compile because `AgentSpec Java ["event1, "event2"]` and `AgentSpec Php ["event3", "event4"]`are of different types, and lists in Haskell can only contain one type. An `AgentSpec a [ByteString]` can be created for any type `a`, but once created it can't be mixed with values of a different type.

I don't know what exactly you're modeling, but typically I'd recommend something like this:

```
data Language = Java | Php

data AgentSpec = AgentSpec 
                     { agent :: Language
                     , events :: [ByteString] 
                     } deriving (Show)

allEvents = [AgentSpec Java ["event1", "event2"], AgentSpec Php ["event3", "event4"]]
```

Based on your comment about writing a library, though, it doesn't sound like this would work. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The library is very simple. This is all it does. You give me a CSV file and an `AgentSpec`. I will read the CSV file and get only those columns specified in the `events` field of the `AgentSpec`. It's a very simple thing to do I'm sure. I'm using this as an exercise to learn how to build libraries in Haskell. I'm beginning to realize that writing binaries and libraries are slightly different, because in the case of a library you have to provide the user of your library with an appropriate abstraction. Whereas this is not required for a binary that you simply run.

Comment: In the example you gave, if the user of my library wants to create a new constructor for the `Language` type, the user will have to edit the library source. That is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

There are some techniques to [implement heterogenous lists in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections). One thing you can do is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data SomeAgentSpec where
    SAS :: AgentSpec a -> SomeAgentSpec

allEvents :: [SomeAgentSpec] -> [ByteString]
allEvents aspec = concatMap ev aspec
    where ev (SAS a) = events a
```

then,

```
\> let a = AgentSpec Java ["1.", "java"]
\> let b = AgentSpec Php  ["2.", "php" ]
\> allEvents [SAS a, SAS b]
["1.","java","2.","php"]
```

Comment: this could work but is this an idiomatic way to accomplish this? Meaning, would a professional Haskeller, with the same problem, choose your solution as a possible way to solve the problem?